# ¿Cómo pasar un datatable a un reporte de crystal reports?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, crystal-reports

Estoy haciendo una aplicación windows forms, en la cual hago una consulta a mi base de datos en sql server, el resultado de esta consulta me genera un datatable, quiero saber como puedo recorrerlo para que no me aparezcan todas las columnas, ya que hay algunas que no tienen información, pero no me queda como yo espero, si me pudieran ayudar.

Este es el código:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                if (item.ToString() == "") continue;
                Reportes.ReportePrograma report = new Reportes.ReportePrograma();
                report.SetDataSource(item.ToString());
                this.dgvPrograma.DataSource = item.ToString();
                this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

                this.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                this.crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();            
            }
        }
```

La variable `dt` es mi datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Debes asignar directamente tu DataTable al reporte de esta forma:

```
Reportes.ReportePrograma report = new Reportes.ReportePrograma();
report.SetDataSource(dt);
this.dgvPrograma.DataSource = dt;
this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

this.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
this.crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: si, pero, como digo hay algunas columnas que están vacías, y esas no las quiero mostrar, solo quiero las que tienen valores, por eso la recorro con un for